# Python 3.x writing to spreadsheet - writing data to a cell range in a for loop rather than just two specified cells

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, google-analytics

I am pulling data from Analytics API, and writing to a Google Sheet. I have a for loop, which pulls a line of data from Analytics based on the variables that I specified, and then moves on to the next item of data. What happens when I run the code is that Python outputs the data across two individual cells that I've specified, overwriting previous data that it has printed. I don't know the syntax to ask it to move the pointer to cell B1 after the first loop, C1 after the second loop and so on.

I hope I've been clear as to my requirements - I am very very new to this. The sample of the code I need to edit is below. Many thanks.

Not sure what else to try - I do not know the syntax required.

```
def analytics_response(response):
    for report in response.get('reports', []):
        columnHeader = report.get('columnHeader', {})
        dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get('dimensions', [])
        metricHeaders = columnHeader.get('metricHeader', {}).get('metricHeaderEntries', [])

        for row in report.get('data', {}).get('rows', []):
            dimensions = row.get('dimensions', "google/organic")
            dateRangeValues = row.get('metrics', [])

            for header, dimension in zip(dimensionHeaders, dimensions):

                for i, values in enumerate(dateRangeValues):

                    for metricHeader, value in zip(metricHeaders, values.get('values')):
                         blank_worksheet.update_cell(1,2, dimension)
                         blank_worksheet.update_cell(1,1, value)
```

I expect each dimension and value to be printed on a separate line in Google Sheet. For example, A1 = Dimension1, B1 = Value1, A2 = Dimension2, B2 = Value2 and so on.

Comment: On your last 2 lines, have you tried replacing the first 1 with i?

Comment: Hi geonaut - thanks for your response. Unfortunately if I do that, it throws up this error:   File "HelloAnalytics.py", line 69, in <module>
    analytics_response(response)
  File "HelloAnalytics.py", line 63, in analytics_response
    blank_worksheet.update_cell(i,1, dimension)
  File "\gspread\models.py", line 731, in update_cell
    range_label = '%s!%s' % (self.title, rowcol_to_a1(row, col))
  File "\gspread\utils.py", line 118, in rowcol_to_a1
    raise IncorrectCellLabel('(%s, %s)' % (row, col))
gspread.exceptions.IncorrectCellLabel: (0, 1)

Comment: Oh - because there is no cell 0 on your google sheet (Python is 0 indexed). Try putting  `i = i +1` on the line before `metricHeader, value in zip(....`

Comment: I see! Thanks for clarifying - very new to all this, as you can probably tell. Unfortunately this does the same as before, it prints to the same two cells and overwrites any previous data.

Comment: This function is doing quite a lot. Might be good to split it into 2 parts. First extract all of the data from the API, and put it into a Python data structure, such as a dictionary. Then, in another function, iterate over the dictionary and write it to the sheet. As a general rule, try not to have too many nested `for` loops.

Comment: Would you be able to give me some guidance as to how to format this output as a dictionary?

Comment: Dictionaries are key/value structures (like a real dictionary). You can make an empty one with `results_dict = {}` and then fill it with `results_dict[first_key] = first_value` You will need to work out what your key should be, and the associated result. I recommend taking a day or two and running through some of the basics of Python. Check out: https://docs.python-guide.org/intro/learning/